# Command to cycle through synonyms

Tags: macros, substitution

Is it possible to define a command to cycle a list of predefined synonyms? For example, define a list of adverbs (however, nevertheless, nonetheless, notwithstanding) for the `\adverb` (or something like `\cycle{adverb}`) command so that each time the `\adverb` (or `\cycle{adverb}`) command is called, a different adverb is displayed.

Differentiating between "However" and "however" outputs would be even better (eg. `\cycle{Adverb}` or `\cycle{adverb}` share the same list of synonyms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will cycle through the defined list of words and repeat as necessary.  Capitalized versions are achieved per the OP's request.  A list is defined with `\synonymlist{listname}{item1,item2,item3,...}` and invoked with `\listname` or `\Listname` for the capitalized version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\casecmd{}
\newcommand\synonymlist[2]{%
  \newcounter{#1cnt}%
  \expandafter\readlist\expandafter*\csname#1list\endcsname{#2}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{%
    \stepcounter{#1cnt}%
    \ifnum\value{#1cnt}>\expandafter\listlen\csname#1list\endcsname[]\relax
      \setcounter{#1cnt}{1}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\casecmd
    \csname#1list\endcsname[\csname the#1cnt\endcsname]%
  }%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname\expupperchar#1\endcsname{\bgroup
    \def\casecmd{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expupperchar}%
    \csname#1\endcsname\egroup
  }%
}
\def\expupperchar#1{%
  \ifcase\numexpr`#1-`a\relax
   A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or K\or L\or M\or
   N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or Y\or Z\else
   #1\fi
}
\begin{document}
\synonymlist{adverb}{however, nevertheless, nonetheless, notwithstanding}
\adverb, \Adverb, \adverb\\
\adverb, \Adverb \\
\adverb

\synonymlist{noun}{truck, bike, train}
\Noun{} is a fine noun, different from\\
\noun{} or \noun.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would use `*` for choosing uppercase, rather than changing the list name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makesynonymlist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { g_thompsonh_syn_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { g_thompsonh_syn_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\cycle}{sm}
 {
  \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_thompsonh_syn_#2_seq } \l__thompsonh_syn_tmp_tl
  \seq_gput_right:cV { g_thompsonh_syn_#2_seq } \l__thompsonh_syn_tmp_tl
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \text_titlecase:n { \tl_use:N \l__thompsonh_syn_tmp_tl }
   }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__thompsonh_syn_tmp_tl
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makesynonymlist{adverb}{however, nevertheless, nonetheless, notwithstanding}

\begin{document}

\cycle*{adverb} \cycle{adverb} \cycle{adverb} \cycle{adverb} \cycle{adverb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A modification to choose a random member of the list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makesynonymlist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { g_thompsonh_syn_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { g_thompsonh_syn_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\cycle}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \text_titlecase:n { \__thompsonh_syn_get:n { #2 } }
   }
   {
    \__thompsonh_syn_get:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__thompsonh_syn_get:n
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g_thompsonh_syn_#1_seq }
   {
    \int_rand:n { \seq_count:c { g_thompsonh_syn_#1_seq } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makesynonymlist{adverb}{however, nevertheless, nonetheless, notwithstanding}

\begin{document}

\cycle*{adverb} \cycle{adverb} \cycle{adverb} \cycle{adverb} \cycle{adverb}

\end{document}
```

[image]